# Measuring non execution time with gettimeofday()

Tags: c, linux

i launched two processes with two different priorities on one process (using taskset).
I would like to measure the non execution time of the process => time where one process is waiting for th other to get the CPU resources.

How can i do this?

Comment: gettimeofday() may help you determine overall elapsed time, which could indeed be an ingredient in your solution  `man proc` and reading the entry for `stat` may help you figure out execution time.

Comment: User-space Linux has better `clock_gettime` facilities for realtime, process, and thread time measurement. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) overview.

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)